# No page refreshing when sending the form using phpmailer

Tags: php, css, ajax, forms, phpmailer

Attempting to combine a phpmailer with a feature that will allow you to send the form without the need to refresh the page. Generally everything looks good, only the email is not sent. On a clear code about phpmailer everything works.

I would like the e-mail to be sent without the need to refresh the page. Maybe someone had a similar problem?

index.html

```
<form name="ContactForm" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 2000;
    $('.btn-default').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if(name == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
                '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Name!</span>'
            );
            $('#name').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var email = $('#email').val();
        if(email == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
                '<span style="color:red;">Enter Email Address!</span>'
            );
            $('#email').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if( $("#email").val()!='' ){
            if( !isValidEmailAddress( $("#email").val() ) ){
                $('.message_box').html(
                    '<span style="color:red;">Provided email address is incorrect!</span>'
                );
                $('#email').focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        var message = $('#message').val();
        if(message == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
                '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Message Here!</span>'
            );
            $('#message').focus();
            return false;
        }   

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.message_box').html(
                    '<img src="Loader.gif" width="25" height="25"/>'
                );
            },       
            success: function(data)
            {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.message_box').html(data);
                }, delay);

            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // $name= $_POST['name'];
    // $email= $_POST['email'];
    // $tel= $_POST['tel'];
    // $message= $_POST['message'];
if ( ($_POST['name']!="") && ($_POST['email']!="")){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'bf4908e76c4186';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'fe1e3963078670';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('pawel@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('pawel@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

    //Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content 
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = $message;


    $mail->send();
if($send){
    echo "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>
    Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.
    </span>";
}
else{
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>
    Sorry! Your form submission is failed.
    </span>";
    }
}
```

Displays the subtitle to me : "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly." but unfortunately not the mailbox empty.

Comment: Your checking if the mail is sent by checking `if($send)`, but you never define the `$send`-variable. If you're unsure if the email is passed along to your PHP page, do a `var_dump($_POST);` and check what it contains. You also have fatal errors in your code (you have `try` without `catch` or `finally`).

Comment: Why are you adding the same address twice? I also hope that those username/password aren't your real ones???

Comment: Could I ask you for a code example? I will correct this duplicate address.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the try/catch problem, you have other issues.

The combination of `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 465` will not work; either change to `ssl` mode or change `Port = 587`. This is well-documented in the troubleshooting guide.

Don't use the submitter's address as the from address; it's forgery and will result in your messages being bounced or spam filtered due to SPF failures. Put your own address in the form address, and put the submitter's in a reply-to - see the contact form example provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Below is a solution.

index.html

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset class="margin-10">
      <input placeholder="Name" id="name" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="margin-10">
      <input placeholder="E-Mail" id="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="margin-10">
      <input placeholder="Phone" id="tel"  type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="margin-10">
      <textarea placeholder="Message..." id="message" name="message" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="margin-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 2000;
    $('.btn-default').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if(name == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
            '<span style="color:red;">Proszę podaj swoje dane.</span>'
            );
            $('#name').focus();
            return false;
            }

        var email = $('#email').val();
        if(email == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
            '<span style="color:red;">Proszę wprowadź swoją adres email.</span>'
            );
            $('#email').focus();
            return false;
            }
        if( $("#email").val()!='' ){
            if( !isValidEmailAddress( $("#email").val() ) ){
            $('.message_box').html(
            '<span style="color:red;">Podany adres e-mail jest nieprawidłowy.</span>'
            );
            $('#email').focus();
            return false;
            }
            }

        var tel = $('#tel').val();
        if(tel == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
            '<span style="color:red;">Proszę wprowadź swoją numer telefonu.</span>'
            );
            $('#tel').focus();
            return false;
            }   

        var message = $('#message').val();
        if(message == ''){
            $('.message_box').html(
            '<span style="color:red;">Proszę wprowadź swoją wiadomość.</span>'
            );
            $('#message').focus();
            return false;
            }   

            $.ajax
            ({
             type: "POST",
             url: "mail.php",
             data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message+"&tel="+tel,
             beforeSend: function() {
             $('.message_box').html(
             '<img src="images/loader.gif" width="30" height="30"/>'
             );
             },      
             success: function(data)
             {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.message_box').html(data);
                }, delay);

             }
             });
    });

});

//Email validation Function 
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
</script>
```

mail.php

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if ( ($_POST['name']!="") && ($_POST['email']!="")){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.noreply.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'noreply@noreply.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '123';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('no-reply@noreply.com', 'No-Reply);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

    //Content 
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Message sent from the website.';
    $mail->Body    = "$name<br>$tel<br><br>$message";


    $mail->send();
    echo 'The message has been successfully sent.';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'The message could not be sent.<br>Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}}
else {
    echo "The message has not been sent.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One that was easy to spot is that you ***try{}*** but never ***catch{}*** any errors that may be returned.

This falls under **exceptions** in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Basic rundown is that for every ***try{}*** you need to have at least one ***catch{}*** or ***finally{}*** block for exceptions! You can also have several ***catch{}*** blocks for different exception cases.

So according to the manual in your case you would use something like this:

```
    <?php
    function verify($x) {
        if (!$x) {
            throw new Exception('Verification Failed!');
        }
        return 1;
    }

    try {
        echo verify("Data") . "\n";  //no exception
        echo verify(null). "\n"      //exception

   } catch (Exception $e) { //sees exception present and catches it for processing
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `try` do need either `catch` or `finally` or it will throw a fatal error, so your point is valid. However, there are more things going on with the OP's code.

Comment: Hey, I'm not 100% either but ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. You should provide a code example.

Comment: I also believe that this should be supported by a code. It's hard for me to comprehend it without a sample code.